# Use unbound service(include MediaPlayer) to play video . VideoActivity instance exist long time and not call onDestroy() after call finish(()

Tags: android, service, media-player, android-mediaplayer

[Android, unbound service, MediaPlayer]

Use `unbound service(background service) (include MediaPlayer)` to play video and audio. In service, use `broadcast` to notify the activity update play progress.

The question is :
When in VideoActivity, click close button(call `finish()`) to close the VideoActivity, and jump to MainActivity.  Video is still playing in background service.
When in MainActivity, I click jump button, no response. I find out that - VideoActivity is destroying, not call `onDestroy()` yet. It pass long time before it call `onDestroy()`.

I don't know why? How to let VideoActivity call `onDestroy()` immediately after I click close button?

Comment: check if video is playing first stop it, and then finish the activity

Comment: When I leave the VideoActicity, It will still play in background(only has soujnd). when come back to VideoActivity, play continue(has sound ). So i use background +service to play video.

Comment: share the code how you are playing the video

Comment: I avoid the problems by one tip: when I start VideoActivity, use intent tag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to new one VideoActivity instance.


`public static void instanceVideo(Activity activity, VideoBean bean) {
      Intent i = new Intent(activity, VideoActivity.class);
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      activity.startActivity(i);
  }`


But I still want to know why had the problem before?
Because project code can not share. If share the issue, I must demo it. Sorry to late response. I will demo it on this Saturday.